# regular expressions in python for searching file

Tags: python, python-re

I want to know how to get files which match this type:
**recording_i.file_extension**

Ex:

```py
recording_1.mp4
recording_112.mp4
recording_11.mov
```

I have a regular expression:

```
(recording_\d*)(\..*)
```

My regular expression doesn't works as i want.
Wrong file names which not match my type: lalala_recording_1.mp4, recording_.mp4
But my re works for this examples, however my code should return [] for this examples.
Can u fix my regular expression, please?
Thanks.

Comment: `^(recording_\d*)(\..*)`?

Comment: r"(^recording_\d+)(\.\w{3}$)"--1) use \d+ since need at least one number, 2) \w{3} for three letter suffix, 3) ^ to insure starts with recording, 4) $ to ensure ends after suffix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use**

```
(^recording_\d+)(\.\w{3}$)
```

**Test**

```
import re

s = """recording_1.mp4
recording_112.mp4
recording_11.mov
lalala_recording_1.mp4, 
recording_.mp4"""

pattern = re.compile(r"(^recording_\d+)(\.\w{3}$)")

for l in s.split():
  if pattern.match(l):
    print(l)
```

**Output** (only the desired files)

```
recording_1.mp4
recording_112.mp4
recording_11.mov
```

**Explanation**

```
With r"(^recording_\d+)(\.\w{3}$)"--1) 
- use \d+ since need at least one number
- \w{3} for three letter suffix
- ^ to ensure starts with recording
- $ to ensure ends after suffix
```

**Particular Suffixes**

```
import re

# List of suffixes to match
suffixes_list = ['mp4', 'mov']
suffixes = '|'.join(suffixes_list)
# Use suffixes in pattern (rather than excepting
# any 3 letter word
pattern = re.compile(fr"(^recording_\d+)(\.{suffixes}$)")
```

**Test**

```
s = """recording_1.mp4
recording_112.mp4
recording_11.mov
lalala_recording_1.mp4, 
recording_.mp4
dummy1.exe
dummy2.pdf
dummy3.exe"""

for l in s.split():
  if pattern.match(l):
    print(l)
```

*Output*

```
recording_1.mp4
recording_112.mp4
recording_11.mov
```

Comment: @DarryIG, how to use a list of allowed extensions instead of \w{3}?
Ex: for this file: recording_1.exe - regular expression works. But i don't wanna get exe files. I wanna get only mp4, mov, avi files

Comment: @Nikto--updated answer with how to get list only with particular suffixes (i.e. place desired ones in `suffixes_list` in code example.